# How to secure the request body

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, rest

I have used .NET and C# to create a REST web service for changing passwords. My question is how to secure the request body on the client side using POST ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a REST service the simplest is to use HTTPS/SSL, in this case you are securing the entire transport not just the body.